# How do I write multiple socat statements in a systemd file for restart on failure?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, socat

CODE:
/etc/systemd/system/socat.service

```
[Unit]
Description="socat systemd"
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
User=ubuntu
ExecStart = /usr/bin/socat tcp-listen:1111,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:5555
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I want to forward these:

```
public_ip:1111 to localhost:5555
public_ip:2222 to localhost:6666
public_ip:3333 to localhost:7777
```

What is the format to make all these forwards inside a single socat.service file? If there is no way to do that, can I write multiple socat statements inside a bash file and put that inside ExecStart?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can just run multiple commands sequentially in `ExecStart` by running the commands in a shell:

```
ExecStart=sh -c '/usr/bin/socat tcp-listen:1111,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:5555; /usr/bin/socat tcp-listen:2222,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:6666;/usr/bin/socat tcp-listen:3333,reuseaddr tcp:localhost:7777'
```

2. You can just put these multiple commands in a shell script, add the
   shebang line to it, mark it executable, and put it in `/usr/bin/mysocatscript.sh`, then use that script in `ExecStart`:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysocatscript.sh
```

This is already better than 1., as you can then write your script to abort when one of these things fail, or be more informative.

3. You write a [*template unit file*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#id-1.14.4), i.e., a unit file that ends in `@.service`, let's call it `/usr/lib/systemd/systenm/socat-forward@.service`. You can then pass a parameter `%i`:

```
[Unit]
Description="socat single forwarding"
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "inport=$(echo %i | cut -d: -f1); outport=$(echo %i | cut -d: -f2); /usr/bin/socat tcp-listen:${inport},reuseaddr tcp:localhost:${outport}"
```

Now, you can set up a socat forwarding simply by starting `socat-forward@port_in:port_out`, e.g. `systemctl start socat-forward@1111:5555`.

You can then just write a unit file `socat-connections.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description="socat custom forwardings"
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60
Requires=socat-forward@1111:5555 socat-forward@2222:6666 socat-forward@3333:7777
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Clearly, 3. is the "best" option:

- You actually get a reusable, configurable service.
- You can pull up and down individual forwardings as needed.
- When one of your 3 socat calls fails, only that is restarted, or reported as failing, etc. So, `systemctl status` will actually tell you which forwarding did not work!
- You can set up and take down your set of forwardings through a single service, and
- you can actually make the thing that depends on your forwardings (for example, your development web server, your SSH server, …) depend on the port forwardings, so that only the forwardings needed are set up.

## Remarks

- Probably an indication of you not actually needing a system, but a user service, if the user runnning the program is `ubuntu`, and not `nobody`, or a daemon user
- Should quite possibly depend on networking being established before
- Is this really a use case for `socat`? Looks to me as if masquerading / NAT would do the same for you, but at lower CPU usage.